# Call a converted HTML to JS variable in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

So I converted an HTML page to javascript.
The javascript is an HTML popup that I will like to activate once I click the button
I want the popup to open on the same page as the button page meaning it will overlay the button...
I am really out of my dept...I have been all over the net trying to figure this out...i really don't know what am doing...pls help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://hairdrstl.com/Wall/file.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="maincontent">
    <button id="button">Show Popup</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This kind of popup is commonly called a "modal" popup/window or dialogue box depending on the terms used. Try searching for "jquery modal popup plugin" to begin with. Unfortunately questions about what software library to use are off topic in themselves - better to ask about a problem you are experiencing with one  you are investigating.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using the `<dialog>` HTML tag, rather than putting your modal code in a `.js` file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
                document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('click', () => {
                    document.querySelector('#modal').showModal();
                });
                document.querySelector('#button-close-modal').addEventListener('click', () => {
                    document.querySelector('#modal').close();
                });
            }, { once: true });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="maincontent">
            <button id="button">Show Popup</button>
        </div>
        <dialog id="modal">
            <!-- Modal content here -->
            <h2>Modal Title</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nobis vitae ducimus non sed quam repudiandae dicta officia.</p>
            <button id="button-close-modal">Close</button>
        </dialog>
    </body>
</html>
```